# Conditions under which inequality with absolute values holds

Tags: inequality, absolute-value

I am trying to figure out the conditions under which the inequality

$$|x|>|z|$$

holds, where $z$ is a convex combination of $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$:

$$z= \pi x + (1-\pi) y \quad , \quad \pi \in (0,1).$$

Surely, $ x \ne y $, but which other conditions need to be met?

My first intuition was $y=0$, which is a sufficient condition. A second set of conditions seems to be $|x|>|y|$ and $sgn(x)=sgn(y)$, because then it must hold that

$$|x|>|z|>|y|.$$

Are these the two solutions or is there a more general set? How should I best approach this problem? My approach seems a bit unstructured.

**edit:** please suggest better tags for this problem too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will prove:

$|x|>|z|$ for all $\pi\in(0,1)$ if and only if $|x|>|y|$ or $x=-y\neq 0$

(You should be able to see this result is true by drawing a diagram.)

---

Sufficiency:

If $|x|>|y|$ then for all $\pi\in(0,1)$

$$|x|>\pi|x|+(1-\pi)|y|=| \pi x|+|(1-\pi)y|\geq  |\pi x + (1-\pi) y|=|z|$$

where the second inequality is from the triangle inequality.

If $x=-y\neq 0$ then for all $\pi\in(0,1)$:

$$|z|=|\pi x-(1-\pi)x|=|(2\pi-1)x|=|2\pi-1||x|<|x|.$$

---

Necessity:

If $x=y$ then $|x|=|z|$.

Finally we show that if $|x|<|y|$ then there exists some $\pi\in(0,1)$ such that $|x|<|z|$. Let

$$f(\pi)=|x|-|\pi x+(1-\pi)y|$$

Suppose $|x|<|y|$, then we have

$$f(0)=|x|-|y|<0$$

and so by continuity of $f$ in $\pi$, we have that $f(\pi)=|x|-|z|<0$ for small $\pi>0$.

Comment: Sorry, I made a silly mistake in the case by case (it was wrong...)

Comment: @tomka I fixed it now.

Comment: Thanks, I noticed that something was wrong when I went through my suggested edit.

Comment: Case by case should still be possible, shouldn't it?

Comment: This is case by case. I did the cases $|x|>|y|$, $|x|<|y|$, $x=y$ and $x=-y\neq 0$

Comment: Yes, I got confused by $x=-y$. This seems all correct now, thank you. Right now I am wondering if we can generalize this to the reverse case. So $|x|<|z|$ only iff $|x|<|y|$?

Comment: The proof shows only that if $|x|<|y|$ then there exists a $\pi\in(0,1)$ such that $|x|<|z|$. The condition $|x|<|y|$ does not imply $|x|<|z|$ for *all* $\pi$. For example if $x=-2$ and $y=4$ and $\pi=1/2$ then $|z|=1$ while $|x|=2$

Comment: But for $|x|>|y|$ it's for all $\pi$, if I understand correctly the proof above? The question would be if it is possible to find stricter conditions for the reverse case. But this is a new question perhaps.

Comment: Yes $|x|>|y|$ implies $|x|>|z|$ for all $\pi\in(0,1)$. For the other case sufficient conditions are $y>x\geq 0$ and $y<x\leq 0$. The former condition ensures that $y>z>x\geq0$ while the latter ensures that $y<z<x\leq 0$, so that in both cases $|z|>|x|$ for all $\lambda\in(0,1)$. (I think these conditions are also necessary for $|z|>|x|$ to hold for all $\lambda\in(0,1)$.)

Comment: I think you mean that the sufficient conditions $y>x \ge 0$ and $y<x \le 0$ both lead to the situation that $|x|<|z|<|y|$ hence $|x|<|z|$ surely.